# NameNotFoundException EJB localbinding sometimes found sometimes not

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi

We have Jboss 4.2 and few ears on it.

One application has EJB with local and remote binding. Another one use this EJB. All working fine before.

But from last week something strange happens - sometimes JNDI lookup can found this EJB but sometimes(in most cases) it get NameNotFoundException.

How this can be possible. Where problem can be?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading JBoss? 4.2 is ancient!

Comment: Jboss 7 if you want to stay with the same vendor. Or, if you're tired of bloatware, how about Apache TomEE? TomEE uses a fraction of the memory.